# Confidence interval for population proportion given two means

Tags: binomial-distribution, confidence-interval

I am trying to estimate a confidence interval containing the true number of people who would vote for Trump. So far, I have calculated the mean number of *men* who would vote for Trump and the mean number of *women* who would vote for Trump. I have also rejected the null hypothesis that the means are equal.

How would I go about constructing a 95%-confidence interval for the true number of people (men and women) who would vote for him GIVEN my estimates and rejection of equality between the means?

Comment: I can help you through this but now that the election is over I don't know if you still care

Comment: yes please. i would like that

Comment: Do you want to construct 2 separate intervals? Meaning, one for men and one for women?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what your data looks like, but I will provide an example of what you need to do. Since you want a 95% confidence interval for the proportion that favors Trump (for men and women), and *NOT* the difference between men and women who favor trump, then you can do this in a couple ways. One way being by hand or one way using computer software R. I will use the method by hand first. At the end I supply you with code for R.

Lets say of 200 men, 100 favor trump and of 100 women, 40 favor trump.

Thus, the *proportions* of men and women who favor trump is $$p1 = .50$$

$$p2 = .40$$

We know $$n1 = 200$$

$$n2 = 100$$

Now we need to compute the *Standard Error* (SE)

$$\text{SE}=\sqrt{\frac{p (1-p)}{n}}$$

Thus,

$$SE1 = .035355$$ 
$$SE2 = .0489898$$

Now we need to find the *Z-Value* for a 95% confidence interval, which is 
$$Z = 1.96$$

We can now compute the *Margin of Error*(ME) by using the formula 
$$Z*SE$$

Thus, 
$$ME1 = 1.96* .0353553 = .0692964$$
$$ME2 = 1.96*.0489898 = .09602$$

Now we can compute the *95% Confidence Interval* (CI) for the proportions of men and women who favor Trump, using $p1$ and $p2$, and $ME1$ and $ME2$

Thus, $$CI1= (.431,.569)$$
$$CI2 = (.304,.496)$$

**Alternatively computer software can do this much faster for you**

*prop.test(100,200,conf.level = .95, correct = TRUE)*

$$0.4313609, 0.5686391$$

*prop.test(40,100,conf.level = .95, correct = TRUE)*

$$0.3047801, 0.5029964$$